# mongodb javascript: return document with only matched sub-document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

anyone know how to return the document with only matched sub-document in javascript?

e.g. here is the database records:

```
[
  {"name":"bestbuy",notes:["article IT", "article 2"]},
  {"name":"microsoft",notes:["article IT", "another IT", "article 5"]},
  {"name":"IBM",notes:["article 8", "article 9"]}
]
```

here is my query:

```
collection.find({"company.notes":/IT/}, function(err,result){})
```

result is:

```
[
  {"name":"bestbuy",notes:["article IT", "article 2"]},
  {"name":"microsoft",notes:["article IT", "another IT", "article 5"]},
]
```

but my expected result is:

```
[
  {"name":"bestbuy",notes:["article IT"]},
  {"name":"microsoft",notes:["article IT", "another IT"]}
]
```

any idea?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: thanks, it is more javascript specific i think

Answer (score 2):

You can use *aggregation*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {"notes": /IT/}}, 
    {$unwind: "$notes"}, 
    {$match: {notes: /IT/}}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', name: {$first: '$name'}, notes: {$push: '$notes'}}},
    {$project: {'name': 1, 'notes': 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

yields:

```
{ "name" : "microsoft", "notes" : [ "article IT", "another IT" ] }
{ "name" : "bestbuy", "notes" : [ "article IT" ] }
```

Comment: thanks, I did not try because I found the db schema is different, so I updated my question. would you please shed a light on that?

Comment: and another question: why need to use 2 "$match"s?

Comment: @aaron This is the answer to you first question. If your db schema is different accept the answer and **ask** a new question. You should not create a [chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) question.

Comment: Then I tried, and the code throws, a headache..
Output is:

    collection opened

    D:\Test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:246
            throw message;
                  ^
    TypeError: object is not a function
        at D:\Test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\collection\aggregation.js:317:7

Comment: var results = collection.aggregate([
        {$match: {"notes": /IT/}},
        {$unwind: "$notes"},
        {$match: {notes: /IT/}},
        {$group: {_id: '$_id', name: {$first: '$name'}, notes: {$push: '$notes'}}},
        {$project: {'name': 1, 'notes': 1, _id: 0}}]);

Comment: Hi, @aaron I'm having one question if notes are `zero` then that entire object is not returned! I want it to be returned like `{ "name" : "Microsoft", "notes" : [  ] }` in the result. How to achieve this?